# how to exract details using year in where clause

Tags: mysql

I am new in MYSQL.
Basically I want to extract all details in a table for a particular year in where clause

Example
I have a date column in my table emp eg: 2012-01-12

I don't know the query.

```
select * from emp where ??
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the [**YEAR**](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_year) function:

```
SELECT * FROM emp WHERE YEAR(dateColumnName)=2012
```